# Add two fragments in one Activity in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to add two fragments in one Activity in Android. But on adding, it is giving error;

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.namal.fragments/com.example.namal.fragments.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2695)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2769)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1430)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
>                      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>                         at com.example.namal.fragments.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6178)
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2648)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2769) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1430) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200) 
>                      Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.example.namal.fragments.MainActivity@1602e5b8 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
>                         at com.example.namal.fragments.Pie1.onAttach(Pie1.java:83)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1043)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1268)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1370)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2415)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:376)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:33)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:75)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
>                         at com.example.namal.fragments.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14) 
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6178) 
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2648) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2769) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1430) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.namal.fragments.MainActivity">


    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:name="com.example.namal.fragments.Pie1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/fragment" />

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:name="com.example.namal.fragments.Pie2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fragment"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/fragment2" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainAvtivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Pie1 firstFragment = new Pie1();

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.activity_main);

        if (fragment == null) {
            fm.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment, firstFragment)
                    .commit();

            Pie2 secondFragment = new Pie2();
            fm.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment2, secondFragment)
                    .commit();
        }
    }
}
```

**Layout of Fragment1**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
   >

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="hello_blank_fragment 2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="hello_blank_fragment 3" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="hello_blank_fragment 4" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**Layout of Fragment 2**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    tools:context="com.example.namal.fragments.Pie2">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="hello_blank_fragment 5" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="hello_blank_fragment 6" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="hello_blank_fragment 7" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="hello_blank_fragment 8" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
    com.example.namal.fragments.MainActivity@1602e5b8 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
    at com.example.namal.fragments.Pie1.onAttach(Pie1.java:83)
```

You need to make you activity implements `OnFragmentInteractionListener`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnFragmentInteractionListener {
```